# How should my unit tests handle mocking Windows EventLog?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, mocking, delegates, event-log

I'm working on writing unit tests for a component that utilizes reading/writing to the Windows Event Log and am having trouble wrapping my head around how to best mock this if my goal is to remove external dependencies (reading and writing to the actual event log).

The component uses [EventLogWatcher](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.eventing.reader.eventlogwatcher?view=dotnet-plat-ext-6.0) to subscribe to events such that the event [EventRecordWritten](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.eventing.reader.eventlogwatcher.eventrecordwritten?view=dotnet-plat-ext-6.0) is raised when a specific event is published to the event log and my `ReadEventLog()` delegate function handles logic relating to the newly published event.

My objective in this unit test has been to ultimately test the functionality of `ReadEventLog()` but I fail to see how to raise the `EventRecordWritten` event myself so that `ReadEventLog()` gets called.

I'm looking for any advice on how to properly write unit tests for the Event Log so that I'm not actually writing to the event log but still somehow using my existing `ReadEventLog()` delegate function(since that's the logic I need to test).

Answer (score 0):

Since `EventLogWatcher` does not implement an interface (except `IDisposable`), you should declare a wrapper class around it which implements `IEventLogWatcher` members and event:

```
   public interface IEventLogWatcher
   {
      bool Enabled { get; set; }
      event EventHandler<EventRecordWrittenEventArgs> EventRecordWritten;
   }

   public class EventLogWatcherWrapper : IEventLogWatcher
   {
      private EventLogWatcher eventLogWatcher { get; set; }

      public bool Enabled
      {
         get => eventLogWatcher.Enabled;
         set => eventLogWatcher.Enabled = value;
      }

      public EventLogWatcherWrapper(string path)
      {
         eventLogWatcher = new EventLogWatcher(path);
      }

      public EventLogWatcherWrapper(EventLogQuery eventQuery, EventBookmark bookmark)
      {
         eventLogWatcher = new EventLogWatcher(eventQuery, bookmark);
      }
      public EventLogWatcherWrapper(EventLogQuery eventQuery, EventBookmark bookmark, bool readExistingEvents)
      {
         eventLogWatcher = new EventLogWatcher(eventQuery, bookmark, readExistingEvents);
      }

      event EventHandler<EventRecordWrittenEventArgs> IEventLogWatcher.EventRecordWritten
      {
         add { eventLogWatcher.EventRecordWritten += value; }
         remove { eventLogWatcher.EventRecordWritten -= value; }
      }
   }
```

Now, you can define the `EventLogWatcher` property as `IEventLogWatcher` in your class and pass a `mockEventLogWatcher` object when you are unit testing.

Comment: Thanks for the response. So I'm working on trying this approach now. Suppose I assign a delegate function to EventRecordWritten like such:

mycustomEventLogWatcher.EventRecordWritten += ReadEventLog.

ReadEventLog() only gets called when the EventRecordWritten event is raised (I thought?). How do I raise this event?

Comment: @IsaacPerez, I recommend using `Moq` library. You simply create `mockEventLogWatcher ` as `new Mock<IEventLogWatcher>` and inject the `mockEventLogWatcher` to your class via constructor for example. then you can raise the event by calling `mockEventLogWatcher.Raise(...)`. Of course, you should make a wrapper class for `EventRecordWrittenEventArgs` so you can raise an event with custom `EventException` and `EventRecord`.

Comment: I think that makes sense. I've made a wrapper class for `EventRecordWrittenEventArgs` so that I can customize `EventRecord`. The trouble I'm facing with this is that I am unable to assign a new instance of `EventRecord` to `EventRecordWrittenEventArgsWrapper.EventRecord`. Do you know how I could accomplish this?

Comment: `EventRecord` is an abstract class, you should derive a class from `EventRecord`, then instantiate the child class and pass it `EventRecordWrittenEventArgsWrapper.EventRecord`. @IsaacPerez